# Issue in mocking python unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have written a test as below:

```
class TestLoader(TestCase):

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
@patch('loaders.myloader.DSFactory')
def _initialize_(self, mock_ds_factory):
    self.loader = MyLoader()
    mock_ds = Mock()
    mock_ds_factory.get_ds_for_env.return_value = mock_ds
    self.loader.ds = mock_ds

def test_load(self):

    self.loader.ds.read_file.return_value = json.dumps(self.get_data())

    self.loader.load("test_s3_key") #####IN THIS LINE I AM GETTING ERROR AS MENTIONED BELOW##

@staticmethod
def get_data():
    return {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Associated source is located here: loaders->myloader.py. myloader.py is as follows:

```
from common.ds_factory import DSFactory

class MyLoader:

   def __init__(self):

       self.ds = DSFactory.get_ds_for_env()


   def load(self, file_key):
       print(f"ds : {self.ds}")
       print(f"file read is : {self.ds.read_file(S3_BUCKET, file_key)}"}
       data_dict = json.loads(self.ds.read_file(S3_BUCKET, file_key))
```

But while testing, I am getting error as follows:

```
ds is :<MagicMock name='DSFactory.get_ds_for_env()' id='140634163567528'>
file read is :<MagicMock name='DSFactory.get_ds_for_env().read_file()' id='140635257259568'>

E               TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'MagicMock'
```

I don't understand why, even after mocking return value of read_file with

```
self.loader.ds.read_file.return_value = json.dumps(self.get_data())
```

I am getting `MagickMock` object. I am stuck, not getting any clue how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:
from common.ds_factory import DSFactory

```
class MyLoader:
   def __init__(self):
       self.ds = DSFactory.get_ds_for_env()
   def load(self, file_key):
       data_dict = json.loads(self.datastore.read_file(S3_BUCKET, file_key))
```

1. Issue here i can see is, data-store is not present, it should be self.ds.read_file
2. Please print self.datastore.read_file(S3_BUCKET, file_key) and verify the output.
3. This is the error coming from AWS_S3 bucket Json structure. It seems its not sending the Json value in string format rather than in Magic Mock format.

To more about Magic Mock format, please visit here: https://medium.com/ryans-dev-notes/python-mock-and-magicmock-b3295c2cc7eb

Comment: my bad, it was a typo in question.

Comment: No worries Joy. Did my answer helps?